# Android GCM - crashing when creating the notification on the client

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have this exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.Notification$Builder.setProgress at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatIceCreamSandwich.a
dd(NotificationCompatIceCreamSandwich.java:31)
        at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$NotificationCompatImplIceCreamSandwich.build(NotificationCompat.java:104)
        at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder.build(NotificationCompat.java:558)
        at com.problemio.GCMIntentService.generateNotification(GCMIntentService.java:132)
        at com.problemio.GCMIntentService.onMessage(GCMIntentService.java:71)
        at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:223)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Here is my GCMIntentService.java

```
package com.problemio;

import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.EXTRA_ERROR;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.EXTRA_REGISTRATION_ID;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.EXTRA_SPECIAL_MESSAGE;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.EXTRA_TOTAL_DELETED;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.EXTRA_UNREGISTERED;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_LIBRARY_RETRY;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_MESSAGE;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_REGISTRATION_CALLBACK;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.VALUE_DELETED_MESSAGES;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import utils.GCMConstants;
import utils.SendEmail;

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService 
{
    public GCMIntentService() 
    {
            super(ProblemioActivity.SENDER_ID);
    }

    @Override
      protected void onRegistered(Context ctxt, String regId) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onRegistered: " + regId);
        Toast.makeText(this, regId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

      @Override
      protected void onUnregistered(Context ctxt, String regId) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onUnregistered: " + regId);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onMessage(Context ctxt, Intent message) 
      {
        Bundle extras=message.getExtras();

        for (String key : extras.keySet()) 
        {
            //sendEmail( "Key: " + key , "value: " + extras.getString(key) );

          Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                String.format("onMessage: %s=%s", key,
                              extras.getString(key)));
        }

        generateNotification(ctxt, extras.getString("message"), "New Message");
      }

        // Subject , body
        public void sendEmail( String subject , String body )
        {
            String[] params = new String[] { "http://www.problemio.com/problems/send_email_mobile.php", subject, body };

            SendEmail task = new SendEmail();
            task.execute(params);               
        }    

      @Override
      protected void onError(Context ctxt, String errorMsg) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onError: " + errorMsg);
      }

      @Override
      protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context ctxt, String errorMsg) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onRecoverableError: " + errorMsg);

        return(true);
      } 

      private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message, String title ) 
      {
            int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
            long when = System.currentTimeMillis(); // can change this to a future time if desired

            NotificationManager notificationManager = 
                    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ProblemioActivity.class);

            // set intent so it does not start a new activity
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);        
            Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);            

             Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
             .setContentTitle(title)
             .setContentText(message)
             .setContentIntent(intent)
             .setSmallIcon(icon)
             .setLights(Color.YELLOW, 1, 2)
             .setAutoCancel(true)
             .setSound(defaultSound)
             .build();

            notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }     
}
```

and the crash happens on this line:

```
generateNotification(ctxt, extras.getString("message"), "New Message");
```

Should I just wrap that line in something like this:

```
if ( android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8 )
{

}
```

In my manifest I allow all sdk versions like this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a support library bug filed for this, see [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36502). A fixed v4 support library can be downloaded from [this link](http://yuku-android-util.googlecode.com/git/ActionBarSherlock4/libs/android-support-v4.jar) in [comment #2](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36502#c2).

Comment: should I just maybe put it into a try/catch statement so it doesn't crash the program?

Comment: Try building a fixed support library jar based on [comment #5](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36502#c5) on the bug report page.

Comment: So nothing below sdk 15 will show notifications in this code? The answer #5 is a bit over my head there.

Comment: It will work on any API level except 13. I added a link to download the fixed library.

Comment: I basically wrapped it in a try/catch ...is this about a similar solution?    try
     {
      generateNotification(ctxt, extras.getString("message"), "New Message");
     }
     catch ( Exception e )
     {
     }

Comment: With your workaround, it won't crash but won't work either, with the updated library, you will have no problems.

Comment: you mean it won't work for version 13 or all of them with my solution?

Comment: It will work for all versions except 13, where it will silently fail.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in android-support-v4.jar before rev11.

To get the latest android-support-v4.jar:

1. Open SDK Manager from your IDE
2. Check `Android Support Library` and click install packages
3. Navigate to `yourSdkFolder/extras/android/support/v4` and copy `android-support-v4.jar`
4. Navigate to the location of `android-support-v4.jar` in your project, and paste, replacing the old version